# switching from different timers c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, timer

I'm creating an Windowns phone 8 app(c#), its a countdown interval timer, so there is prepare time(10 sec), work time(20 sec), rest time(10 sec). I have these variables

```
  `TimeSpan prepInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);
   TimeSpan workInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 20);
   TimeSpan restInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);`
```

I can't wrap my head around having them implementing them one after another when they hit 0. So when prepare time is done, the work timer is to start and when thats finised, the rest timer is to start.

Comment: Why not use a timer and use it to count the stages. When one stage ends / hits 0 start the next stage.

Comment: You need a variable to keep track of where you are.  Could be an *int*, you'll like an enum better.

Comment: Do what deathismyfriend suggested- on each timer.Elapsed event kick off the next timer. No need to flux around with timespans.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have some more broken down logic in all of this, maybe you can create some classes based on a simple interface, like the following:

```
interface ITimerAction
{
    int Seconds { get; set; }
    bool Started { get; }
    bool Completed { get; }
    void OnStart();
    void OnComplete();
}

interface ITimerActionList
{
    void Add(ITimerAction action);
    void Work();
    event EventHandler OnCompletedEvent;
}
```

This would then allow you to create an abstract TimerAction class, and TimerActionList

```
abstract class TimerAction : ITimerAction
{
    public virtual int Seconds
    {
        get;
        set; 
    }

    public virtual bool Completed
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    public virtual bool Started
    {
        get;
        protected set; 
    }

    public abstract void OnStart();

    public abstract void OnComplete();
}

class TimerActionList : ITimerActionList
{
    public event EventHandler OnCompletedEvent;

    private readonly IList<ITimerAction> actions = new List<ITimerAction>();

    private bool working = false;
    private Thread myThread;

    public void Add(ITimerAction action)
    {
        if (working)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot add new timers when work is already in progress");
        }
        actions.Add(action);
    }

    protected virtual void DoWork()
    {
        working = true;
        int currentStep = 0, maxSteps = actions.Count;
        while (currentStep < maxSteps)
        {
            ITimerAction action = actions[currentStep];
            if (!action.Started)
            {
                action.OnStart();
            }
            if (action.Completed)
            {
                currentStep++;
                continue;
            }
            if (action.Seconds == 0)
            {
                action.OnComplete();
                continue;
            }
            action.Seconds--;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Completed();
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        if (working)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already running!");
        }
        working = true;
        myThread = new Thread(DoWork);
        myThread.Start();
    }

    protected virtual void Completed()
    {
        myThread = null;
        working = false;
        actions.Clear();
        var local = OnCompletedEvent;
        if (local != null)
        {
            local.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

You could then write the classes that inherit from the TimerAction class, that could handle an action before and after the timer ran through :)

```
class PrepareTimer : TimerAction
{
    public override void OnStart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Preparing");
        Started = true;
    }

    public override void OnComplete()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Prepare ready");
        Completed = true;
    }
}

class WorkTimer : TimerAction
{
    public override void OnStart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Working");
        Started = true;
    }

    public override void OnComplete()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Work ready");
        Completed = true;
    }
}

class CoolDownTimer : TimerAction
{
    public override void OnStart()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cooling down");
        Started = true;
    }

    public override void OnComplete()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cooldown ready");
        Completed = true;
    }
}
```

And then you could test the code as such

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool done = false;
    ITimerActionList mylist = new TimerActionList();
    mylist.Add(new PrepareTimer { Seconds = 1 });
    mylist.Add(new WorkTimer { Seconds = 2 });
    mylist.Add(new CoolDownTimer { Seconds = 1 });

    mylist.OnCompletedEvent += (sender, e) =>
    {
        done = true;
    };
    mylist.Work();
    while (!done)
    {
        // timer is running
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
}
```

(Console program, but i guess that also goes to demonstrate?)

Comment: I sometimes get carried away :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on deathismyfriend's and Hans Passant's suggestions:

```
var start = new DateTime();
var stage = 0;

var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);

timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
{
    var elapsed = DateTime.Now - start;
    int duration = stage == 1 ? 20 : 10;

    if (elapsed.TotalSeconds > duration)
    {
        start = DateTime.Now;
        stage++;

        if (stage > 2)
            timer.Stop();
    }
};

start = DateTime.Now;
stage = 0;

timer.Start();
```